# How to Benchmarking : bandwidth improvement from using GZIP with cURL (PHP)

Tags: php, curl, gzip, libcurl

I am trying to benchmark the bandwidth saved from setting GZIP to active with cURL(PHP).

I did this by `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING , 'Accept-Encoding: gzip');`

Below is the documentation for **CURLOPT_ENCODING** :

> The contents of the "Accept-Encoding:
>   " header. This enables decoding of the
>   response. Supported encodings are
>   "identity", "deflate", and "gzip". If
>   an empty string, "", is set, a header
>   containing all supported encoding
>   types is sent.

Now is there an easy & convenient for me to check the bandwidth used when I have GZIP ON and when I have it OFF ?

Comment: By using this function, you are telling the active curl resource `$ch` to tell the server that it accepts gzip encoding when it requests `$ch` URL. It has nothing to do with your current page being gzipped when sent to client. (I understood that you are using this to gzip current page, correct me If I'm mistaken).

Answer (score 0):

You need to get Curl to visit two different URLS, both with the same content, but one with Gzip enabled on the target server and the other without. Curl's function `curl_getinfo()` provides a lot of information to do with the time it took to download and the content length, from that you may be able to get the information you want.